# Strategies for Testing Payment Callbacks

Tags: callback, payment-gateway

I'm working on setting up a payment page on my website, and most of the payment providers I'm setting up use callbacks to notify me about transaction statuses.

I've never developed a callback listener, so I'm curious if there are any strategies for testing them. Obviously, my dev machine isn't hooked up with a domain name, so I won't be able to receive the callbacks from the payment providers.

I'm a bit stumped. Building this without being able to listen to callbacks is going to challenging. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I can think of two options:

1. Set up my dev machine with DynDNS so that it can receive POSTs from the payment provider. This has the unfortunate side effects of not being possible in a complicated network, and being a pain to set up, and creating a security vulnerability, since my server isn't hardened.
2. Use a service. I found [one that might](http://requestb.in/)  fit the bill. I think I can set it up to work, and then I should be all set to go.